# SIGSEGV error with BFS Algorithm

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I have a BFS algorithm error.
Have tried to debug with the `gdb` but I don't understand why I get this.

Can anyone tell me why i get a `SIGSEGV` error with the code below. Does it depend on the compiler that you use how the pointers are addressed? As there is an invalid pointer error in the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 8;

struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *next;
};

class Graph
{
  private:

    int visited[MAX];
    int q[8];
    int front, rear;

public:

    Graph();
    void BFS(int v, Node **p);
    Node *getNode_Write(int val);
    static void addQueue(int *a, int vertex, int *f, int *r);
    static int deleteQueue(int *q, int *f, int *r);
    static int isEmpty(int *f);
    void del(Node *n);
};

// initialize data memeber
Graph::Graph()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        visited[i] = FALSE;

   front = rear = -1;
}

// function that implements breadth first search (BFS) algorithm
void Graph::BFS(int v, Node **p)
{
    Node *u;

    visited[v-1] = TRUE;

    cout<<v<<"\t";

   addQueue(q, v, &front, &rear);

   while(isEmpty(&front) == FALSE)
   {
       v = deleteQueue(q, &front, &rear);
       u = *(p+v-1);

       while(u != NULL)
       {
          if(visited[u->data-1] == FALSE)
          {
            addQueue(q, u->data, &front, & rear);
            visited[u->data-1] == TRUE;
            cout<<u->data<<"\t";
          }

          u = u->next;
       }            

     }
  }

 // Creates a node
 Node *Graph::getNode_Write(int val)
 {
     Node *newNode = new Node;
     newNode->data = val;
     return newNode;
 }

 //Adds node to the queue
 void Graph::addQueue(int *a, int vertex, int *f, int *r)
 {
    if(*r == MAX -1)
    {
       cout<<"\nQueue Overflow.";
       exit(0);
    }

    (*r)++;

    a[*r] = vertex;

    if(*f == -1)
       *r = 0;
   }

   // Deletes a node from the queue
   int Graph::deleteQueue(int *a, int *f, int *r)
   {
       int data;

       if(*f == -1)
       {
         cout<<"\nQueue Underflow";
         exit(0);
       }

       data = a[*f];

       if(*f == *r)
          *f = *r = -1;
       else
         (*f)++;

      return data;      
    }

    // checks if queque is empty
  int Graph::isEmpty(int *f)
  {
     if(*f == -1)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
  }


  // deallocate the memory
  void Graph::del(Node *n) 
  {
       Node *temp;

      while(n != NULL)
      {
           temp = n->next;
           delete n;
           n = temp;
      }
   }

  int main()
  {
      Node *arr[MAX];
      Node *v1,*v2,*v3,*v4;

      Graph g;

      v1 = g.getNode_Write(2);  
      arr[0] = v1;  
      v1->next = v2 = g.getNode_Write(3);
      v2->next = NULL;

      v1 = g.getNode_Write(1);
      arr[1] = v1;
      v1->next = v2 = g.getNode_Write(4);
      v2->next = v3 = g.getNode_Write(5);
      v3->next = NULL;  

      cout<<endl;

      g.BFS(1,arr);

      for(int i = 0; i<MAX; i++)
          g.del(arr[i]);    


    }
```

Comment: Run your program in a debugger, the debugger will stop at the location of the crash. Walk up the function call stack to your code (if it's not there already) and the edit your question to only include the relevant parts of the code, plus values of involved variables, unless you can figure it out yourself of course.

Comment: @SouravGhosh _"Have tried to debug with the gdb bu don't understand why I get this. ..."_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ whoops.. I missed the "docs" part.

Comment: @SouravGhosh No problem. Most probably the OP just uses the debugger wrong, similarly as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646715/sdl2-tutorial-program-segfaults) ;-) ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, I am working on it. But, I don't understand a negative count for my question. I understand there are many BFS algorithms online but this seems to be using more pointers and I preferred it to pursue further despite of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is an uninitialized array `arr` in the stack frame of `main`. Only `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` become initialized. At the end of main it is iterated over the whole array and `delete` is called in `Graph::del(Node *n)` on a garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Does it depend on the compiler that you use how the pointers are addressed?"*

No, it doesn't depend on the compiler primarily. As Joachim pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646835/sigsegv-error-with-bfs-algorithm#comment49357599_30646835):

To see the real source of the error, you should just step up the stack trace, and check out how all the variables and parameters were actually set.

Most likely you've been calling some undefined behavior, due to missing, or wrong variable initializations.